# An American driving in Europe -- what to learn?

Tags: europe, driving, driving-licenses

I've been driving over 20 years, but never outside the US. European driving is quite different, I hear, both rule of the road and other drivers' habits. If I was to drive in Europe what should I learn and how? Is it possible to take a "European Driving" course while still in US, so that I would arrive to Europe ready to rent a car on the 1st day? By "Europe" I mean continental EU, Germany and neighbors, not the left-side-of-the-road UK.

Comment: I really don't think it is all that different, and that is said as an American (who has driven all across Europe). Sure, you should look up the road signs for the country, and take it easy to begin with. Learn how to drive a manual as well (if you don't already know - it is getting less common in the US), or pay lots more for the rental car...

Comment: And speeds are in km/h, so when it says 80, just match your speedometer to what it says on the sign :)

Comment: Only difference is that there's no right turn on red in Europe. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Except for when there is a special green arrow - then you have the right turn on red  again. And sticking to the rightmost lane except for overtaking is taken more seriously.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This question is really too broad ([this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57313/) about driving just in Italy is borderline, and the "continental EU" has at least as much diversity of conditions and laws as North America). Please narrow it down if you can to specific areas of concern, like laws on passing, or right turns, or speed limits in a particular area.

Comment: It's not that different.  If you're a comfortable driver, it's a fairly easy adjustment..with one possible exception.  Most rentals are manual.

Comment: @JonathanReez hold my beer (says Austria and starts a pilot project)

Comment: First thing to learn is that Europe is made of many very different countries. You don't drive the same in Germany, France, Spain or UK.

Comment: USA highway signs tend to emphasize the route number, where European signs the destination city. Route markers are generally much smaller, too.

Comment: I'd recommend the metric system.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus That seems to depend on the country as well. In Germany, you as well take the A 1, the A 6 and so on.

Comment: This is far too broad. Europe is very culturally diverse and driving standards and norms differ massively. Advice that applies, say, in Greece wille be completely different from, say, Germany.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've driven for many years in the US and also gone through the process of getting my driver's license (again!) in the Netherlands.  The below is based on my experience and there are some subtle differences between countries so beware.

First, to get it out of the way, almost all cars in Europe are manual transmissions, although some rental cars are automatics.  In fact, if you take your driving test with an automatic, you are not allowed to drive a manual transmission until you take the exam again (after a mandatory 2 year waiting period!) with a manual transmission.

The other answers touch on some common things, but the single most important difference is in right-of-way.  In Europe, they rely much less on stop signs and stoplights to regulate traffic.  Instead, they rely more on traffic circles, "shark's teeth" and right-of-way rules.  There are some other things as well.

### Traffic Circles

There are two major forms of traffic circles: standard ones and "turbo" ones.  Standard ones are the usual ones where one could potentially drive around them indefinitely.  Turbo traffic circles may have one or two lanes for traffic entering from each side and do not permit making a full trip around the circle.  Instead, one lane typically allows exiting to the right or straight across the circle, while the other permits exiting straight cross or 3/4 of the way around.

### Shark's Teeth

Shark's teeth are just yield signs painted on the road in a "teeth" pattern.  Much like there is a white line painted on the road where there is a stop sign in the US, these shark's teeth indicate you are to yield to traffic at the intersection.

### Right-of-Way

The right-of-way rules take the most time and practice to get used to.  There are two important aspects to this:

1. In the absence of other indications on right-of-way, you must yield to the person coming from the right.
2. Yellow diamonds are used to indicate when your road has right-of-way and you do not need to do this.

When there are no stop signs, yield signs or yellow diamond "right-of-way" signs at an intersection, then you must yield to the person on your right.  These types of intersections are most common in residential areas.  It is often difficult to know if someone is coming from the right unless you actively slow down and look carefully to your right before entering the intersection.  It is important to do this though as cars coming from the right WILL expect you to yield.

There are a few more subtle aspects to this.  You must yield right-of-way to a bus that is leaving a bus stop within city limits, but you do not have to do this outside city limits.  Also, the yellow diamonds that regulate right-of-way are posted before the intersections they govern within city limits, but outside city limits the "right-of-way" starts after the intersection (and the sign is posted after the intersection) and continues through the next intersection, at which point it ends unless the signage repeats.

### Other Differences of Note

**Right turn on red**.  Many countries do not allow right turn on red.  Where it is allowed, such as Poland, it is governed by a special right-arrow light at a traffic light.  If the right arrow light is there and green, you can turn right on red after first coming to a full stop and then yielding to any other traffic.  If there is no right arrow light, right on red is not allowed.

**Traffic cameras**.  Many common traffic violations (speeding, going through red lights) are monitored by traffic cameras rather than patrol cars.

**Speed limit signage**.  Speed limits in Europe are more complex.  There are 3 areas where speeds are governed by "global limits" for that class of road: this is within built-up areas, on expressways and on motorways.  If there is no explicit speedlimit in these areas, then the speedlimit is the national limit for that type of road.  For example, in the Netherlands unless otherwise posted, the speed limits for a built-up areas is 50 km/h, an expressway is 100 km/h, and a motorway is 130 km/h.  The key thing is unless otherwise posted. The European way is to "cancel" the previous explicit limit, which means the global limit for that class of road applies.  Note also that each country has its own limits for these three classes of road, which, unhelpfully, is only posted when you first enter the country.

I'm not aware of any course in the US that teaches you all this.  In practice, I think the most important thing to be aware of will be yielding to those on the right in residential areas.  You can comfortably practice this around your own neighborhood in the US.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_to_the_right has a longer explanation and images of the relevant road signs. The priority road system is probably the most important thing for Americans to be familiar with when driving in Europe, as it does not exist in the USA.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The page you link to claims "Most states in the United States enforce priority-to-the-right at uncontrolled intersections"

Comment: @npostavs True, but it's the rest of the system that will be foreign (pun not intended) to Americans, and uncontrolled intersections are pretty rare in the US anyway.

Comment: There are also "turbo roundabouts" in the US, they're not unique to Europe. Right of way rules are likewise exactly the same. Yielding to busses is also mandatory in most US cities.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, but all these things are far less common in the US, and even where right-of-way rules apply in the US, they are not followed strictly, much like rules about no passing on the right. You are free to post your own answer, but as an American who "relearned" how to drive in Europe, these stand out in my mind.

Comment: @JonathanReez Are you sure about that? AFAIK there is exactly one turbo roundabout anywhere in North America...and it's [in Canada](https://trid.trb.org/view/1399684)! Plenty of conventional multi-lane roundabouts now though, even a couple in my little town of 23,000.

Comment: I think it wasn't mentioned yet: There is also no turning right on a red traffic light, right and left turns at intersections usually have their own traffic lights. At least in Austria, I am not sure about other European countries however.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've seen a few in Washington state. Although they might not technically be "turbo" roundabouts, they work pretty much like described in this post where you use the rightmost lane to take the first exit and the leftmost lane to use another exit.

Comment: Some of this answer is generic for (continental) Europe, some of it is specific to particular countries, I think The Netherlands.

Comment: When driving in the Netherlands, and there is a traffic jam and you hear sirens, you should expect the emergency vehicles to go between the 2 left most lanes, as opposed to the shoulder of the road. This is differend from the country next to it, Germany where the emergency vehicles take the shoulder of the road (feel free to add this directory to your answer @Eric)

Comment: @Ferrybig Actually, it's the same in Germany and Luxembourg (where it's called the “Rettungsgasse”).

Comment: @JonathanReez That's a regular roundabout. I think what the answer describes are the roundabouts where there is a small curb between the lanes *inside* the roundabout. You would have to cross it to change your direction after committing to a lane. I thought those were typically Dutch.

Comment: @Relaxed I Just realized I totally said it backwards.... In Germany its common for emerge services to go between the lanes, even if there is a shoulder, but in the Netherlands, emergency services prefer to go on the shoulder if it is there, if there is a traffic jam

Comment: @pat3d3r Thanks.  I edited the answer to include this.

Comment: @Eric, for your 'normal speed limits in the Netherlands' you missed an important class. 80 km, on rural roads which are not motorway or express way. The easiest way to find out local speed limits is a sat nav/GPS system. Much easier than trying to remember what you saw at the country border, specially if you are driving through several countries.

Comment: Don't understand all this "no right turn on red except when there's a green arrow".  There is a green arrow therefore you are not turning on red, but turning on the green arrow.  There are multiple variations of this, where the main lights are showing red, but a green arrow provides an exception for the direction indicated.

Answer (score 16):

Do not pass on the right.

Learn the right of way rules.

Here is the US military driving manual for Germany.  It comes the major rules and if followed will work for almost everywhere in Europe.
http://www.usareurpracticetest.com/germany/documents/manual.pdf

Comment: Ouch. I browsed through that document for some minutes and found a major bug: "If  the  owner  cannot  be  located,  leave  a  note  indicating  the  driver’s  name,  address,  telephone number, and insurance company." That is not enough. You MUST wait until the owner can be located or you call the police. The threshold for hit and run is 50 € (AFAIR), not 1500 €.

Comment: In addition to that, the rental agreement will pretty much require you to *always* call the police for *any* incident anyway. In general, you will need the "Aktenzeichen" (file number) of the police investigation to file an incident report with the rental company.

Answer (score 15):

In some European countries there some things that are compulsory to carry in the car. 
Check for each country you're visiting what's required.

Confirm what's provided by the hire co. and what you need to source.

Such things as first aid kits, fire extinguishers, Hi_vis jackets (one per person or driver only), disposable breathalyzer kits, spare bulbs, warning triangles (2 in Spain), snow chains (seasonal I guess).

Comment: snow chains would indeed be seasonal. They're also mandatory to use under certain conditions in some countries, while in others they're illegal to use under any condition (but may be carried).

Comment: Spare glasses if you need them to drive (Spain).

Answer (score 6):

Right-of-way rules are extremely important because everyone else drives as if you were going to respect them too, so it is easy to get into an accident by not knowing them. Other answers are covered this in great detail.

It is also important to know the default speed limits for the cities and between cities you will be travelling. The most puzzling sign I found in Denmark was a red circle with a bar over a number. This indicates that the shown number is *no longer* the speed limit. No units are specified but this number is in km/h instead of mph as in the US. The main point though is that the sign tells you what is not the speed limit but not the new limit. Instead, you return to be within the limit for the type of road and area (city-center, residential zone, intercity road) and, indeed you must know what that is.

Actual speed limit can be complicated. In Iceland, the sign is a matrix which I never managed to read entirely before passing! In one dimension, the type of vehicle is shown, in the other, the type road. The speed limit is the number, in km/h in the square which corresponds to your situation.

The wrong-way sign is a red circle with a white horizontal bar in it. This is seldom seen in the Americas.

[image]

Same for the no stopping and no parking ones:

[image]

Parking in Europe is vastly different from North America. The rules can be complex and local to some city zones too. In one place, I think it was Akureyri (IIRC), we had to buy a paper parking meter place in the car and manually indicate the marked time on it. Other places have sidewalk colors and I've many places where people parked partially on the sidewalk (although this might not have been legal). Going with the flow ensures you be no worse than the average but that won't make it legal in Europe. In contrast, California has laws that make following the flow a legal requirement in some cases!

While I visited 25 European countries, I have driven in 20 of them, relying on trains for the other 5, so I have a variety of experience driving, although based on so many less common rules, I'm sure to not have gotten everything 100% right. In the US, Canada, Ecador, Peru and Brazil, I have driven thousands of kilometres and the rules there a closer to those in Canada (Where I drove regularly for the best part of 30 years) and the US.

Comment: yes, the parking disks are commonly used in many European countries. Kinda strange that one didn't come with your rental car but they're cheap. Overall you're correct. One caveat though: the speed limit cancellation sign has a variant where a speed is listed on it. If that's the case it cancels that specific limit only, leaving you with the next highest limit indicated on that segment of road. E.g. a 130kmh road was restricted to 100 and then further to 90. If the 90 is cancelled, the limit reverts to 100. If no speed is listed on the cancellation, it reverts to 130.

Comment: @jwenting Care to provide a reference? The speed limit cancellation sign without a number is **not** a speed limit cancellation. It is a cancellation of all prior restrictions (including speed), whereas the sign with the speed listed, afaik, cancels the speed limit to the default, not the previously posted. I.e., 130, in your example, not 100.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP That's how I was taught to interpret it 27 years ago when I got my driver's license. And that's how colleagues of me have been fined for driving 130 after a 90 was cancelled but an earlier 100 was not.

Comment: @jwenting A country specification would be in order. What you describe, is an incredibly complicated rule (suppose, someone enters a street after the 100 sign, but before the 90). http://www.strassenschilder.de/vorschriftszeichen/ende-der-geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung/ This reference in German states that such a sign reverts to the default and make no mention of anything else. I can only guess that the 130 in your unfortunate example was actually *above* the default speed limit for the kind of road you were on.

Answer (score 4):

#### Road safety and traffic rules differ within the EU

Road safety and traffic rules differ within the EU, see an [official page](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/driving-abroad/road-rules-and-safety/index_en.htm) for this, going deeper in each [country-specific](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/road_safety/going_abroad/index_en.htm) one. BTW main rules are common.

Main differences I can recall:

- In the European Union member states [in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_on_red#Europe), **it is illegal to turn on a red light**, unless it is indicated otherwise, for example by a green arrow on a red light (but in this case you have to allow any other one --cars as people-- to pass before you).
- Almost pernicious is the fact that if there is a **supplementary green arrow** to turn (left or, more often, only right) **you can turn only when it is lighted on**, even if in the main semaphore there is a full green lighted on (They are changing those one with a straight arrow instead of the full green).

  [image]
- **Keep the right** as you can, **do not overcome on the right** (it may be allowed if the street is with three or more lines -- of course switch right with left in *UK & co.*).
- Usually a *more more* **narrow spaces** available for the cars, specially in the historical centers. Narrow streets and you can find car parked with 2-3 fingers of distance between them. (Just to understand why many people buy little cars).
- In some countries (if I remember well e.g. in Austria), the **highways** are on payment on a year base and the payment is displayed with a sticker on the front glass. Picture are taken and fine issued if not present. In other countries you pay when you exit but you need to take the ticket when you enter (It's payed on a base proportional to the km used).
- Remember to check **for which countries the insurance is valid**. The car insurance is obligatory.
- As already reported by Eric, *"almost all cars in Europe are manual transmissions, although some rental cars are automatics"* (and you have to pay more for this).
  This means also that they accelerate from a stop more promptly, and that they afford the curves with **a different driving style** (with an automatic car you need to start to decelerate before then with a manual front-wheel drive one); with sufficient high speed it can cause you at least discomfort.
- Remember to drive on the **left side** of the road in Cyprus, Ireland, Malta and the United Kingdom. It seems silly but after that you drive for a while on one of the single track road of Scotland, crossing few other people, you can easily forget it. Moreover you cross another tourist with the same amnesia!
  In those countries I strongly suggest you to rent an automatic car.

Comment: +1 For the "it is illegal to turn on a red light" Never forget this. Red light = total stop of car.

Comment: The point on supplementary green arrow isn't intirely correct. It goes like this: green arrow lit => turn allowed and you have the right of way; red arrow lit => turn illegal; no arrow lit => follow the main lights.

Answer (score 3):

1. If is best to have an International Drives License (which is basically just a translation to several languages) available from AAA. Many do not bother with this and is generally not required by car rental companies.
2. Some cities have "ZTL" (limited traffic) areas where traffic is limited to vehicle with proper stickers/registration) and the fine can be large.
3. If there may be snow some countries (Italy is one) and it does snow you must have snow chains at least in the car. We got caught in a sudden/unexpected snow and had to buy snow chains which are often provided free for the asking when renting.

Se the answer by [@canonacer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/131764/64710) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I've been living in Austria and driving in Europe for 15+ years now and have some experience with driving in the US.

The only practical differences I can think of are:

- left turns on highways are not as common here, you mostly leave highways by moving to the right lane and taking an exit from there
- when turning, people really keep to their lane (e.g. when three lanes in one direction turn left all at once, a truck in the middle lane doesn't take half of the innermost left lane too...)
- no passing on the right
- you can pass school buses on bus stops no problem
- lanes, parking lots outside as well as underground parks tend to be narrower here than in the US

Comment: About the school busses: if they have hazard lights on while driving, you are not allowed to overtake. If they have it on while at the bus stop, overtake with extreme care an walking speed, only. This applies to Germany, no idea about Austria.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get used to narrow roads, narrow parking places, narrow parking garages 
and almost no street parking space anywhere in cities. Not even in suburbs.

Cycling is a thing in Europe and not all cyclists follow rules.
Motor cycles are also common and their riders do sometimes also not follow the rules.

But the most important thing you have to learn is the [*odd* road signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_European_road_signs) you will encounter. Almost no texts, which may come in handy as if you don't speak multiple languages, but lots of pictograms which slightly differ from country to country.

As you specifically asked about Germany, as an example which may come surprising to you, take this sign:

[image: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrsberuhigter_Bereich]

A friendly place, isn't it? So, could anything bad happen here? **Yes,** because this sign indicates a *living street* and speed is restricted to 5 km/h. Parking is also restricted, and you have to yield to traffic when you leave it again. Failure to do any of this will lead to a fine or even worse, an accident.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've given you a downvote because of the phrase "bikers are outlaws". While I concede that some/many bicyclists follow their own minds, it is patently false to say they are outlaws (in all the EU countries I am aware of) because there are indeed traffic laws for bicyclists and how they should interact with other traffic.

Comment: I've given you an upvote because I shuddered to imagine an outlaw biker coming up that friendly street and knocking down that boy with the ball.  That's just the kind of thing they do.

Comment: "Biking is a thing in Europe and bikers are outlaws. " Are you talking about criminal motorbike gangs?

Comment: That sign, or one very similar, exists in the Netherlands as well. Be extremely cautious driving there, people expect you to drive at a walking pace. Typically the area tends to have a lot of speed bumps, especially at the entrances, and other speed reducing features like chicanes.

Comment: 5 km/h? I _walk_ faster than that without even trying!

Comment: @KlaymenDK me too, only difference is I’m not sorry.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's the idea. Those signs are placed in some residential areas. It allows children to play outside more safely.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know the number of 7 km/h, but yes, that's the idea: "Schrittgeschwindigkeit" – you only drive as fast as someone could walk. But these streets are only in living areas and usually not where you go through.

Comment: The law in the Netherlands has changed, it is now 15 km/h rather than 'walking speed' for the areas with the funny sign. Walking speed always was unclear, walking for humans or for horses, so now it is clear.